# Remove duplicate rows and keep the duplicate base on a specific column's data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I need to delete the duplicates of my data based on whether the supervisor is listed or not, but if both duplicates have "NULL" then I still need to keep one. How can I do this?
Please see the image as a reference.

[image]

Comment: Regardless if two rows have both nulls or both Jane Smiths as the supervisor, one each will be removed when performing the remove duplicates function. Please add sample data and desired result as I suspect you are trying to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know if it does what you want, you need to change the sheet1 to the sheet containing your data and sheet2 to a blank sheet. Change the numbers 3 (myuniqueID) and 6 (MySupervisor) to be the columns containing that information. It does assume there is a column with some form of unique ID that will identify the duplicates?

```
Option Base 1
Sub copydupeswcrit()
'This sub works through data in wsF and copies any duplicates to wsT
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim wsF As Worksheet: Set wsF = Sheet1
    Dim wsT As Worksheet: Set wsT = Sheet2
    Dim x As Long, y As Long, i As Long, t As Long, q As Long, n As Long, MySupervisor As Long, MyUniqueID As Long
    Dim myarr1 As Variant, MyxArr As Variant, myarr3 As Variant
    i = 1
    MyUniqueID = 3
    MySupervisor = 6
    'create array from sheet
    myarr1 = wsF.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ReDim MyxArr(UBound(myarr1, 1)) ' array to check if unique ID already checked
    'Prepare array to receive data
    ReDim myarr3(UBound(myarr1, 1), UBound(myarr1, 2))
    For x = LBound(myarr1, 1) To UBound(myarr1, 1)                      'scout through array
        For y = LBound(myarr1, 1) To UBound(myarr1, 1)
            If x = y Then GoTo MyNxtY                                   'if looking at the same line move to next y
            If myarr1(x, MyUniqueID) = myarr1(y, MyUniqueID) Then                         'if ID numbers match do this
                For n = LBound(MyxArr) To UBound(MyxArr)                    'exit loop if ID already checked
                    If myarr1(x, MyUniqueID) = MyxArr(n) Then GoTo MyNxtY
                Next n
                If myarr1(x, MySupervisor) <> vbNullString Then    'check if supervisor column (5 or E) contains information
                    For t = 1 To UBound(myarr1, 2)      'copies first line to new array if supervisor detail present, else copies second line
                        myarr3(i, t) = myarr1(x, t)
                    Next t
                Else
                    For t = 1 To UBound(myarr1, 2)      'copy new line to array3
                        myarr3(i, t) = myarr1(y, t)
                    Next t
                End If
                GoTo MyNxtX
            End If
MyNxtY:
        Next y
    For t = 1 To UBound(myarr1, 2)
        myarr3(i, t) = myarr1(x, t)
    Next t
i = i + 1
MyNxtX:
        MyxArr(x) = myarr1(x, MyUniqueID) ' creates checking array
    Next x
wsT.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(myarr3, 1), UBound(myarr3, 2)) = myarr3 ' pastes array to new sheet
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Justin, it did not work as there is bug in 
myarr1 = wsF.Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Comment: I changed it to
myarr1 = wsF.Range("A2:G1430").CurrentRegion
and it did "run" but it did nothing.

Comment: Hi Karen, the currentregion command selects everything contiguous with a cell so if you data starts in A2 just change the range to "A2". It does assume there are no blank columns or rows in the data you are interested in. If you have modified the code it may be best to move your data so that it starts on A1 then try the code as is, if that does not work post more detail on the layout of your data, I tried to make the code flexible but it does make some assumptions.